# How to display php function in WP shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I should say that I am only starting my journey with PHP so probably that's why I can not do such a simple task.
I have got a simple php code which I need to use as a shortcode. I got no problem in make code for shortcode but what I cant understand is how to insert that php function inside. The php function I am trying to insert is:

```
$(  element  ).airport([ 'moscow', 'berlin', 'stockholm' ]);
```

And as a shortcode I made a such code:

```
    function home_words_shortcode() {


    return  $element .airport([ 'moscow', 'berlin', 'stockholm' ]);
}
add_shortcode( 'home-words', 'home_words_shortcode' );
```

I did a research online and found what I thought similar to my code and tried to convert to circumstances but nothing seems to work.
Could anyone help me please.

Comment: that's not a php function. that's javascript/jquery... and you cannot execute either from the other.

Comment: hmmm... Right I see. Thanks. Need to find a different way to achieve the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to add this script as a shortcode, but this could be a way:

```
function home_words_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'element' => '#default-element',
        'cities'  => '',
    ), $atts, 'home-words' );

    $cities = json_encode(array_filter(explode(',', $atts['cities'])));

    return "
        <script>
            jQuery('{$atts['element']}').airport($cities);
        </script>
    ";

}

add_shortcode( 'home-words', 'home_words_shortcode' );
```

It works with a shortcode like:

```
[home-words element="#element" cities="moscow,berlin,stockholm"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you, but this is not a php function:

```
$(  element  ).airport([ 'moscow', 'berlin', 'stockholm' ]);
```

As I can see, it's a jquery code, maybe  you have problems with the selectors, you can get all the knowledge rigth [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp). And a [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_id)

I hope this will be useful for you.

PD: I'm not a native english speaker, so, be comprehensive please :)